# How reboot Google Cloud Machine Group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I created a Load Balancer on `GCP` with a group of machines created from a template, a backend service, a frontend service etc ...

The template has a startup script

- clones the sources from a GitHub repository,
- compiles the sources
- starts the application.

If I update the sources how can I reboot?
So the startup script update the app

Comment: Managed Instance Groups have the ability to rollout updates.  See the following article and see if it helps in the story ... https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups

Comment: @Kolban is right, use rollout feature to deploy your new instance template

Comment: Thank you guys `Kolban` `guillaume blaquiere`